# Ambiguous values in Lang and requestLang

Tags: scala, playframework, securesocial

Using: PlayFramework 2.3 and SecureSocial (compatible version with 2.3)

Im receiving this error in the ViewTemplate:

```
[error] /Users/einevea/projects/einjar/einevault/econcepts/modules/eusers/app/services.eusers/MyViewTemplates.scala:29: ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both method request2lang in trait Controller of type (implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)play.api.i18n.Lang
[error]  and value lang of type play.api.i18n.Lang
[error]  match expected type play.api.i18n.Lang
[error]   override def getStartSignUpPage(form: Form[String])(implicit request: RequestHeader, lang: Lang): Html = views.html.eusers.custom.startSignUp(WUPage(Messages("securesocial.signup.title")),form)(request, lang, env)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message means that you have tried to call `getStartSignUpPage` and that takes an implicit `play.api.i18n.Lang` but there are two implicit `Lang` instances in your scope, so therefore the compiler does not know which one to choose.

The first one is the value lang which you have imported or defined (either as a value in the template or as an implicit parameter in the parameter lists of the template)

The second one is a built in one that comes from play `Controller.request2Lang` which knows how to extract Lang from the request to select the language that the browser said that it accepts (in the Accept-Language header).

You could work around this in a few ways: avoid having two `Lang` instances in scope, provide the parameters explicitly where you call `getStartSignUpPage` or make the implicit parameter list a regular parameter list.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jonhan, I provide the parameters explicitly and it worked now.