# After update getting "Ambiguous implicit values" Error

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

i'm trying to update my play application to 2.3.

I have written an own html helper:

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, options: Seq[(String,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler:  views.html.helper.FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)

@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    @options.map { v =>
        <label class="radio inline">
            <input type="radio" id="@(id)_@v._1" name="@name" value="@v._1" @(if(value == Some(v._1)) "checked" else "") @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs)> <span>@v._2</span>
        </label>
    }
}
```

The error i get is:

> > both method implicitJavaLang in object PlayMagicForJava of type => play.api.i18n.Lang  and value lang of type play.api.i18n.Lang   match
> >     expected type play.api.i18n.Lang
> >             
> >     **ambiguous implicit values**

I don't understand what is problem here. To remove the implicit lang is not an option for me cause in some html helpers it is necessary. Also i don't want to make lang to a "real" parameter. I want to use the advantage of implicits.

Is there a solution for this?

Any help would be cool :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200820/ambiguous-values-in-lang-and-requestlang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can safely remove the implicit lang parameter, because Play 2.3 has already one in its implicit context.

Answer (score 0):

Options are either to remove where the implicit lang is declared (check your imports, perhaps an `import play.core.j.PlayMagicForJava._` exists), or pass the value explicitly. Implicit arguments in the second argument list can still be passed explicitly.